# Google Account switching in Firebase Console

Tags: firebase, google-account, firebase-console

I am not able to switch between my Google accounts in the Firebase console. I have 2 accounts, one for personal and one for work.

In the Firebase (https://firebase.google.com) page, the Google account dropdown (upper right) is populated with my accounts, but when I log in to the Console, it is always signed into my default, personal, account (https://console.firebase.google.com/) and I can not switch to my work account.

This happens even if I'm logged into my work account on the Firebase page and click the Console link. ?authuser=1 is appended to the URL, like in most Google applications when switching accounts, but it doesn't seem to work in Firebase Console.

Any reasonable suggestions? Making my work account my default account messes up a lot of other Google products I actively use (Music, Hangouts, etc)

Comment: I use different Chrome windows each logged into a different account, and switch between them as needed.  Learning the keyboard shortcuts on your desktop OS makes this easy.

Comment: Sounds like an answer Doug! :-)

Comment: Struggle with the same issue. But I dont want to handle two windows for that.

Comment: A slight improvement is to use the People feature of Chrome. It still requires two windows, but let's you always keep instant access. I have two "People" set up with my work and home emails respectively, and this feature makes it easy to keep my chrome windows separate

Comment: @David this is what has worked best for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

It's really hacky, but you can work around the absence of an account-switching feature in Firebase console by manually editing the URL.

The Firebase console URL seems to default to the first Google account you're logged into.

```
https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/....
```

Manually changing the number in the URL to the position of the Google account in the account switching dialog you might see with Gmail works for me. The number is zero-indexed, so use 1 for the second account, 2 for the third account...

```
https://console.firebase.google.com/u/1/project/....
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is the same approach for all google products I use...

I use multiple browsers for multiple google accounts. I am logged into my work gmail account in chrome. I am logged into my personal gmail account in firefox. I have a 3rd rare dummy account I use edge for.

It sounds like work should be on Chrome for you since you use firebase and other important things that Chrome does well. Firefox is more than capable for music and hangouts (and non-dev stuff).

This is how I keep personal and work life separate. Close firefox when you need to get work done or vice versa. Works really well for me the last 5 years